# syntax error in lint when using #!/usr/bin/env python3

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, lint

I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
@ Copyright 2022  All rights reserved
```

When lint runs, it throws a syntax error on line 1.

Problem is, it was working fine a few days ago.  I fixed some whitespace further down the code and now I can't get lint to get past line 1.

Thoughts

Comment: Well, that IS a syntax error - the copyright notice would need to be inside a comment, it's not valid Python code.

Comment: I deleted it and tried with just the shebang and still get a syntax error